# WPF: Does calling new on a static variable deattach the subscriptions?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datepicker

In my code I have a DatePicker controller is defined as a static field.

```
private static DatePicker datePicker;
```

every time this datePicker is called, it's assigned to a new object.

```
datePicker = new DatePicker();
```

then several listeners are attached to it such as:

```
datePicker.Loaded += onDatePickerLoaded;
datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += onSelectedDateChanged;
```

Also, there are listeners attached to the TextBox and Popup of the datePicker itself.

This pattern is used in the code multiple times.

My question is does calling `datePicker = new DatePicker();` unsubscribe all the previous attached subscriptions?

In other question when I call **new** on a static field does the old object become eligible to the garbage collection?

Comment: You are creating a completely new object (hence why the keyword is `new`!) so anything attached to the old one is gone.

Comment: That's what came in my mind the first thing, but I have read some other answers about how it's a good practice to unsubscribe every subscription to avoid memory leaks. As a lazy coder, I wanted to make sure to avoid unsubscribe all the repetitive hundreds of subscriptions made after calling New ! Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidG *anything attached to the old object is gone*, not everything, new'ing up an object prevents the event references from being garbage collected.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: I always wondered how this is dealt with when using lamda expressions as event handlers. They can't be unsubscribed, so my guess is the would "stick around". If so, that, often used pattern must be considered as an anti-pattern in my opinion.

Comment: @JeremyThompson What are 'event references'?  Events are _methods_: an `add` handler and a `remove` handler; it is not possible to 'reference' an event.  _Subscriptions_ are references from the publisher to the subscriber in the form of delegates.  Dangling subscriptions may keep the _subscriber_ from being garbage collected, but only as long as the publisher is still reachable.  Once the publisher is unreachable, so too are the subscriptions, and they are eligible for GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is does calling datePicker = new DatePicker(); unsubscribe all the previous attached subscriptions?

No.  However, if there are no outstanding references to the **old** `datePicker` instance, then the old subscriptions are useless, and they will be wiped out when the old date picker gets garbage collected.  While the subscriptions are technically still there, they won't receive any events unless the old `datePicker` is still being used somewhere.

> In other question when I call new on a static field does the old object become eligible to the garbage collection?

Failing to remove the subscriptions will not, on its own, prevent the old instance from being garbage collected. Event subscriptions are a reference *from* the publisher *to* the subscriber, so once the publisher becomes unreachable, the subscriptions will also be unreachable.

Note that this does not work both ways.  If you have a permanent, static publisher and various short-lived subscribers, and those subscribers never unsubscribe, then their subscriptions *will* keep them from being garbage collected.  Thus, it is a good habit to unsubscribe to events that you are no longer interested in.  You can also avoid the dangling subscriber issue by using a [weak event pattern](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns).  To be clear, this is not the scenario you described, but the reverse; it applies in cases where the publisher is expected to outlive the subscribers.

Comment: Great! I have some question.In case of my Loaded Event  'datePicker.Loaded += onDatePickerLoaded;' ,  what is the publisher and what is the subscriber. Based on my understanding the subscriber is my dateController and the publisher is FrameworkElement which is in the System.Windows namespace. If yes, what makes the publisher unreachable in this case?

Comment: Also, when we say "publisher is not reachable", is it from the subscriber's standpoint? For example, if I have 2 subscribers A and B (let's say WPF controllers that are subscribed to the Loaded event). If A was unloaded or like in my case I called new on it, does this mean the publisher is not reachable from A. Thus, A is GC. With the fact that B is still reaching the publisher. hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: Simply put, an object is 'reachable' if there is a reference to it somewhere in the program, where that reference is either global (e.g., a static field), a variable on the stack, or a member of another reachable object. [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Reachability_of_an_object) for a better explanation. In your example, if A and B subscribe to P, then A will be reachable by P even if you 'forget' about A. That's because the publisher retains a reference to each subscriber.  That's what I describe in my last paragraph. While P is reachable, A can't be GC'd.